# What is the Bootstrap 3 container size 1200px or 1170px?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ipad, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, retina

Which is right?

Same question for medium web, tablet and mobile?

Comment: I don't exactly understand the question. The iPad3 display resolution is 2048 × 1536 Pixels, if you're looking for that.

Answer (score 0):

These are the container sizes for desktop:

- 1170px
- 970px
- 750px

Comment: Thanks for reply. There was an issue before with the column sizes: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12808#issuecomment-47693107   Do you know what the column sizes are now for 1140? I am trying to make a photoshop 3.2 template. thanks

Comment: It's 1170px, not 1140. The documentation is now correct. The column width is 97.5px

Comment: Hi @Matteo Ok I am confused again. I know the container is 1170 but the actual design area is 1140 with the 30px on each side it is 1170.